# Purpose of A Closed Surface in Gauss's Theorem

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Why is it necessary to consider a closed surface while dealing with Gauss's Law? From the mathematical point of view, it is pretty clear that since we need to calculate the area of the Gaussian Surface, it must be a closed one. But if we had to give an explanation based on Physics, what would it be?

As far as I think, we generally consider a closed surface in order to have complete knowledge of the status of the electric field at every point inside the surface.

Comment: *since we need to calculate the area of the Gaussian Surface, it must be a closed one* Why do you think that’s the reason? A hemisphere is not closed but it has an area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gauss's law in the integral form  given by
$$\oint_\mathcal{S}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{S}=\frac{Q_\text{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$$
The left-hand side is the flux of the field, and the right-hand side proportional to the charge enclosed by the surface.

A more naive way to say that Electric Charges are the sources of the electric field. Sometimes it's taken as the definition of the electric charge. It's useful to think of the field as a fluid flow field (which easy to visualize) and electric charges as the source of the fluid (positive corresponds to source and negative to be sink).

Now let's suppose you want to measure the strength of the source, What can you do? Well, what you can do is to take, a large membrane and make a close surface around the point where the strength is to be measure and see How much water is flowing outward and inward (that is flux). It's clear why we have used a closed surface, If we take an open surface we will never able to measure the strength as there might be an open-end from where the flux might go out or in,  which will create an error in our calculation.

---

A more general proof can found in any elementary text.